# Why result output is integer even result is defined as float?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
        float result;
        result=(340/101);
        cout<<"Result="<<result;

}
```

in this code **result is=3**, i'm curious about why is that? what is the prevention of this cause and it can be seen a minor problem but it really deprecate my results in my data analysis program.

EDIT:  thanks for the answers, i was trying the code below and it also gives me 3, so that's why i confused now i'm clear.

```
result=(float)(340/101);
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`340` is an integer and `101` is an integer, so `340/101` performs integer division.  The result of the division is converted to a `float` when it is assigned to `result`.

You need to cast one to a floating point type to have floating point division performed:

```
result = static_cast<float>(340)/101;
```

or just use a floating literal:

```
result = 340.0f/101;
```

Comment: "You need to cast one to an integer type..." You mean cast to float, right? ;)

Comment: @James, why not just `float(340)/101` instead of the ugly `static_cast`?

Comment: @7vies: Because casts are *supposed* to be ugly. They should scream at you. Otherwise, you easily miss them or use them accidentally.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Fair enough, but only for casts that can potentially be dangerous, which is not the case here.

Comment: @7vies: Actually, casts from `int` to `float` *can* be dangerous. Consider `(float)123456789` which results in `123456792.0f` which is off by 3 because float only has 24 bits of precision.

Comment: @FredOverflow: That is no more dangerous than a literal (123456789.0f), and I think such concerns are exaggerated.

Comment: @FredOverflow: oh, that's so far from being dangerous in the usual C++ sense of "dangerous" ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow:  Oh.  Yes, absolutely right.  Thanks @Andy T for the interim correction.

Answer (score 4):

Because the expression `(340/101)` is evaluated independent of its surrounding context. `int/int` always results in an `int`. It makes no difference if you store that `int` in a `float` variable later on.

Answer (score 2):

It's due to integer division, as both operands in the division operation are integers. Either cast one of the numbers to a float, or utilize floating point syntax:

```
result = (340.0 / 101.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the `(340/101)` is considered in isolation. Since both operands of `/` are `int`s, the compiler generates code for integer division. Then, since you're assigning that result to a `float`, it generates code to convert the resulting `int` to `float`.

To get floating point division, you need to ensure that (at least) one of the operands to `/` starts out as a `float` (or `double`), such as: `float result = 340.0f / 101.0f;`